# show/hide div in another container

Tags: html, css, nested

Good day,
I am wondering if someone can have a look at this help me understand why the second tab button doesn't seem to work.
I am trying to make wrapper div, left side div with the label buttons and a right side div to display the content.
If I put the  show/hide div on the left with the buttons then it displays and hides like it should but, when its in the div on the right the button does nothing.

```css
#chk:checked~#tab1,
#chk2:checked~#tab2 {
  display: none;
}

div.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 300px;
}

div.forred {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
}

div.left {
  width: 20%;
  float left;
}

div#tab1 {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div#tab2 {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div.right {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
}

input.tabs {
  display: none;
}

label.tab_button {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px inset black;
  background: #30E514;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <input type=checkbox id=chk class=tabs>
    <label for=chk class=tab_button>tab 1</label>
    <input type=checkbox id=chk2 class=tabs>
    <label for=chk2 class=tab_button>tab 2</label>
    <div id=tab1>
      OVER HERE
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div id=tab2>
      OVER HERE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second "button" doesn't work because take a look at this part of your css :

```
#chk:checked ~ #tab1,
#chk2:checked ~ #tab2 { display:none; }
```

Here, you apply to the sibling of #chk:checked a display:none; It works for the first "button" because in your HTML you can see that #tab1 is a sibling of #chk:checked but, as you can already guess it, #chk2:checked is not a sibling of #tab2. So move up your div#tab2 just after div#tab1 and then it will works.

Also, I took some time to modify your code to put them at first invisible, then, visible if someone click on tab1 or tab2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>Untitled 1</title>

<style>

    div.wrapper {width: 100%; background: black; height: 300px;}
    div.left {width: 20%; float left;}
    input.tabs { display: none;}
    label.tab_button { 
        float: left; 
        padding: 15px 0px; 
        font-weight: 600;
        text-align: center; 
        color: #FFFFFF; 
        border-bottom: 1px inset black;
        background: #30E514; 
        width: 100%;
    }
    #tab1, #tab2 {background: red; width: 100%; text-align: center;}
    div.right { width: 80%; float: right;}

    #tab1, #tab2 {display:none;}

    #chk:checked ~ #tab1,
    #chk2:checked ~ #tab2 { display:block; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk" class="tabs">
        <label for="chk" class="tab_button">tab 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" class="tabs">
        <label for="chk2" class="tab_button">tab 2</label>
        <div id="tab1">
            TAB 1 HERE
        </div>
        <div id="tab2">
            TAB 2 HERE
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right div
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you that does help. I'm trying to get the div to display on the right hand. So when the buttons in the div container on the left is pressed it displays that div on the right of it. Is there a way to have the button display the div contents in the other div on the right?